# Unique list elements in Python, but prefer capitalized values

Tags: python

If elements are added to an `array` (or `set`, `dictionary`), how can it result in unique elements (which `set` does case-sensitively) but prefer capitalized words instead of their lower-case alternatives (e.g. Apple instead of apple).

Example:

```py
items = []

items.append('apple')
items.append('orange')
items.append('Apple')
items.append('grapes')
items.append('Orange')
```

Expected result:

```
[ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'grapes' ]
```

It'll be good to keep the original order by first occurrence (as in the result above).

I don't want to use any 3rd-party packages for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured a simpler approach using a `dictionary`:

```py
dict = {}

for i in items:
  il = i.lower()
  if not il in dict or i[0].isupper():
    dict[il] = i

print(list(dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `set`, `capitalize` and `lower`:

```
unique_items = [i for i in list(set([i.lower() for i in items]))]

for i, unique_item in enumerate(unique_items):
     if unique_item.capitalize() in items:
         unique_items[i] = unique_item.capitalize()

unique_items.sort(key=lambda e: items.index(e.casefold()))

print(unique_items) # ['grapes', 'Apple', 'Orange']
```

Comment: Yes... indeed. Please see the corrected version

Comment: can  add `unique_items.sort(key=lambda e: items.index(e.casefold()))` to get the correct order

Comment: Just added it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. While your answer is good, but I figured a simpler approach (see answer).